# How to post an empty array (of ints) (jQuery -> MVC 3)

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3

Using jQuery I am posting an array of `int` to my MVC 3 application by putting the array in the data parameter like so: `data: { myIntArray: myIntArray }`. In my controller, the receiving action has as a parameter `int[] myIntArray`.

This goes well in most cases, except when `myIntArray` is empty. In the request I see the following `myIntArray=` (note that there is no space after "="). Back in my MVC 3 controller this gets translated to an array containing one `int`: 0.

It doesn't seem to me like I am doing something terribly wrong here by posting an empty array. I can work around this by handling the case where the array is empty in a different way. Nevertheless, I feel that this should be possible.

Thanks in advance.

**Extra info:**

- I use jQuery 1.5.1 (cannot upgrade for this project).
- `myIntArray` is
  initialized with `new Array()`.

Comment: Is `myIntArray` in javascript set to be an empty array `[]` or `undefined`?

Comment: @Gaby, it is initalized like so `myIntArray = new Array()`

Comment: can you check with firebug and see what gets posted in the two cases (*with empty and with a filled array*)

Comment: @Gaby, with values: `myIntArray=1&myIntArray=2&myInt...`. Without values `myIntArray=`.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is with MVC 3 considering `myIntArray=` as an `int[] { 0 }`. I wouldn't know what else should be in the request that could indicate an empty array.

Comment: @Matthijs Are you sure that `myIntArray` is an array? Objects serialized as `"myIntArray="` are usually empty strings. Empty arrays are always serialized as `""`. Check if `jQuery.isArray(myIntArray)` is `true` before your post.

Comment: @Matthijs, the issue seems to be that MVC will handle each `myIntArray` url parameter as a value of the array (*since it is a `int[] myIntArray`*). Perhaps you should avoid including the `myIntArray` url param if it empty, from the jquery side..

Comment: @Paolo, yes I'm sure, I debugged even to check if it was still an array at the moment of posting. I also posted `data: { myIntArray: new Array() }`: same result. `Empty arrays are always serialized as ""`, the value of it is serialized as `""`. But as I said, I wouldn't know what else to expect to be honest.

Comment: @Gaby, that's what I am doing now. This results in `int[] myIntArray` being `null` on the MVC side. I do a check if it is `null` and then initialize it with an empty array. But this is a really a hack.

Comment: @Matthijs `jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "...", data: { intMyArray: [] }, });` (at least the latest version 1.6.2 with FF 5.0) perform an HTTP POST request with no parameters, so I can't figure out why how you can get this `myIntArray=`. Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Matthijs You are right, I'm getting the same problem with 1.5.1. So one solution could be to switch to latest version (1.6.2).

Comment: @Paolo, ok, thanks for the response. I don't think we can switch to the latest jQuery now anymore though in this project (almost completed). I'll just keep my workaround, add some comments to it and check the rest of the project if anything has this problem. Also I will bring this to the attention to the rest of the team for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var myIntArray = new Array();

// add elements or leave empty
myIntArray.push(1);
myIntArray.push(5);

var data = myIntArray.length > 0 ? { myIntArray: myIntArray } : null;

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("someAction")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

or use a JSON request:

```
var myIntArray = new Array();
// add elements or leave empty
myIntArray.push(1);
myIntArray.push(5);

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("someAction")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(myIntArray),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: what does `traditional = 'true'` specify

Comment: both these ajax requests would send json data wouldn't they? if so why Json.stringyfy

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid, the [`traditional`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) parameter specifies the desired serialization style so that it plays well with the default model binder. The first request sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` whereas the second sends a JSON request.

Comment: Your first suggestion is about what I do now. However, don't those both result in the array being `null` in the MVC 3 action? I would like to just receive an empty array.

Comment: @Matthijs Wessels, yes both result into receiving `null` on the controller action if the array is empty on the client side. As far as receiving empty arrays is concerned, the default model binder doesn't support this but you could write your own custom model binder for the `int[]` type and achieve this functionality if you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone lands on this question trying to resolve this...

**This is a bug in MVC** (that still exists in MVC 4 in 2019, duh):

- when you `POST` an empty form parameter into an action method that has an array-mapped variable or model - this results in an 1-element zero array `{ 0 }`.

I found no other way than to deal with it on the back-end.

Here's another question discussing it: [ASP.NET MVC Int Array parameter with empty array defaults to {0}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036329/asp-net-mvc-int-array-parameter-with-empty-array-defaults-to-0)